oh-my-zsh takes first character when opening a new shell
After running poetry shell with oh-my-zsh, I get the following error message when it tries to activate the virtual-env:
*[main][~/coding/ensure_import]$ poetry shell
Spawning shell within /Users/mac10.12/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/ensure-import-3q-JXftD-py3.11
[oh-my-zsh] Would you like to update? [Y/n]
[oh-my-zsh] You can update manually by running `omz update`
*[main][~/coding/ensure_import]$ mulate bash -c '. /Users/mac10.12/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/ensure-import-3q-JXftD-py3.11/bin/activate'
zsh: command not found: mulate

I have never heard of mulate, but it kind of looks like it's supposed to be emulate if you squint a bit?

Assuming that the file generating the error (ensure_import) is not code you have written yourself, I would at least have a look into this file; maybe there is a comment explaining what this strange mulate command is supposed to do. Would be interesting.

ensure_import isn't a command in this case, it's just the working directory. poetry shell is the command being run.

But also I think i figured it out: the [oh-my-zsh] request to update stole the first character of the next line of the script.

Running omz update fixed the problem for me -- I think the prompt to update oh-my-zsh was stealing the first character of the emulate command.
I found the answer (and borrowed the command output) from this post here (after running Google translate).
I also made a feature request for no-input update reminders.
